# A more pythonic way to apply `lower` to the first part of a string?

Tags: python, string, split

I have strings that need to be applied `lower` to their first part before a dot and left flamboyant after. My solution looks like this :

```py
>>> field = "WhatEver.strinG"
>>> f"{field.split('.')[0].lower()}.{field.split('.')[1]}"
'whatever.strinG'
```

It works but I feel bad writing it. It feels strange splitting and gluing things back. Is there a better way around?

Comment: Seems perfectly fine to me

Comment: The only thing you might want to do is only split the string once outside of the f-string. `start, end = field.split('.'); rebuilt = f"{start.lower()}.{end}"`

Comment: Might be the most pythonic way there is to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there has to be a dot present and only non whitespace characters, so you want to convert `WhatEver.strinG` but not `WhatEver`, you can use a regex with a positive lookahead to assert the dot:

```
import re

fields = [
    "WhatEver.strinG",
    "WhatEver"
    ]

pattern = r"^[^\s.]+(?=\.)"

for field in fields:
    res = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: m.group().lower(), field)
    print(res)
```

Output

```
whatever.strinG
WhatEver
```

If you also want to allow spaces and only do the call to lowercase when there actually is an uppercase char A-Z in the first part:

```
^[^.A-Z]*[A-Z][^.]*(?=\.)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FFcZ5L/1) for the matches.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the suggestion and explanations!

Answer (score 1):

What you have is fine aside from doing the split twice, but I think using `join` is less verbose than an f-string.

```
field = 'WhatEver.strinG'
parts = field.split('.')
parts[0] = parts[0].lower()
'.'.join(parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
field = "WhatEver.strinG"
ind = field.index(".")
field[:ind].lower() + field[ind:]
# OR
f"{field[:ind].lower()}{field[ind:]}"
# 'whatever.strinG'
```

Comment: I didn't think of the index, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An option using a regex and `re.sub`:

```
import re

out = re.sub(r'^[^.]+', lambda x: x.group().lower(), field)
```

Output: `'whatever.strinG'`